# Split String and get desired part

Tags: c#, string, split

Is there any way to get the portion of string after the last "_" forexample;

```
string1 = "A_110_23_09_ABC"

result1 = "ABC"
```

---

```
string2 = "A_110_23_09_ABC_555"

result2 = "555"
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? This seems a legit question.

Comment: I didn't understand either. I searched but couldn't find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var s = "A_110_23_09_ABC";
var result = s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf('_') + 1);
```

Comment: Thank you for help.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using .NET 3.5 or higher, you could do it by LINQ to Object. The code would be something like :

```
var result = string.Split('_').Last();
```